# use conditional tags / if / else on a custom function in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, thumbnails, attachment

How can I hide the img-tag if there is no attacment?

(function is from this tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automagic-post-thumbnails-image-management/)

```
<img src="<?php get_attachment_picture();?>" />
```

I need something like this:

```
<?php if ( get_attachment_picture()) { ?>
<img src="<?php get_attachment_picture();?>">
<?php } else { ?>
show nothing, not even av default image
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you need by having the function return the thumbnail, rather than echoing it.

Delete these lines from the function:

```
else:
    $related_thumbnail = "images/default_thumbnail.jpg";  //define default thumbnail, you can use full url here.
```

and replace

```
echo $related_thumbnail;
```

with

```
return $related_thumbnail;
```

Your code then becomes

```
<?php
$attachment = get_attachment_picture();

if ( ! empty($attachment) ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $attachment; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

I haven't tested any of this, so I may have missed something, but that approach should work.

By the way - I can't see why the function has these lines:

```
ob_start();  
ob_end_clean();
```

It might be worth deleting them,

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the "standard" article thumbnail, you could just use the `has_post_thumbnail`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail

```
<?php 
//This must be in one loop

if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    // if there is no thumbnail, do nothing (or whatever you want) here
}
?>
```